# Thumbnail screenshot of a webpage

Tags: website, thumbnails

I am just wondering how to make a thumbnail of a webpage to display ? I've seen so many websites like stumbleupon , dzone have a thumbnail images of other websites. Is there any simple way to that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe [BrowserShots](http://browsershots.org/) or [BrowsrCamp](http://www.browsrcamp.com/) will do what you are after. Just visit those web sites, whack in the URL to the web page you wish to generate a thumbnail for, then let it do it's business.

Or, you could go with a more native approach by using the [ScreenGrab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1146) Firefox plugin:

> Screengrab! saves webpages as images…
>
> It will capture what you can see in the window, the entire page, just a selection, a particular frame... basically it saves webpages as images - either to a file, or to the clipboard.

Alternativly, you could try [FireShot](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5648) as well

Answer (score 0):

[Easy Thumbnails](http://www.fookes.com/ezthumbs/)

> Easy Thumbnails is a popular free
>   Windows utility for creating accurate
>   thumbnail images and scaled-down/up
>   copies from a wide range of popular
>   picture formats.